# How to create a unique hyperlink for each element in an angularjs array

Tags: angularjs

So i have an array of random names and i want each name in the array to have its own hyperlink. When displayed it should basically be a list of names that each link to different pages, how do i go about giving each name in the array a different hyperlink? I attached a snippet of the html and js.

```js
$scope.artists=[
{
    name: "Noelle",
    rank: "Gold",
    worth: 752000,
},
{
    name: "John",
    rank: "Silver",
    worth: 700000,
},
{
    name: "Shem",
    rank: "Green",
    worth: 5687952,
},
```

```html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="artist in artists | orderBy: order | filter: search">
        <h3>{{artist.name}} - {{artist.worth | currency:'£'}}</h3>
        <div class="remove" ng-click="removeArtist(artist)">x</div>
        <span class="rank" style="background:{{artist.rank}}">{{artist.rank}}</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Can you give an example of what you want the hyperlink to be?

Comment: okay so ive made an array of names made in js that i display through ng-repeat. 
But i want the outputted names to be hyperlinks, if that makes any sense.


So the 3 names in the array snippet Noelle, John & Shem would be displayed but i also want each name displayed double as a hyperlink that can lead to a profile page for each person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would include the href as part of the artist object - and have a standard URL that differs only in the name of the artist.

In the following I am interpolating the artist into the href of the a. Note that I am coding this as a link property with the artists full name in case there are two artists with the same first name.

Note that hovering over the link text will show you the link href - if you click it - nothing will show since there isnt a corresponding page to navigate to.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.artists=[
    {
        name: "Noelle",
        rank: "Gold",
        worth: 752000,
        link: "noelle-smith"
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        rank: "Silver",
        worth: 700000,
        link: "john-jones"
    },
    {
        name: "Shem",
        rank: "Green",
        worth: 5687952,
        link: "shem-willis"
    }]
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="artist in artists | orderBy: order | filter: search">
          <h3>{{artist.name}} - {{artist.worth | currency:'£'}}</h3>
           <span class="rank" style="background:{{artist.rank}}">{{artist.rank}}</span><br/>
         <a href="/artists/{{ artist.link }}.html"> View Artist</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This wasnt exactly i was looking for but the concept helped me figure out how to achieve what i wanted! :)

Comment: Great - happy to help. If you could mark this answer as accepted - then other devs will know the issue has been resolved - Happy Coding.